# Add class to element using jQuery after successfull ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-core

I am attempting to add an `'active'` class to an `<li>` when the `<li>` is clicked. This is what the structure of the `<li><a>` looks like:

```
<li onclick="paginationChange(2)" id="2" class="page-item">
    <a class="page-link" href="#">2</a>
</li>
```

As each `<li>` has an id attached to it I thought it would be as simple as:

```
$('#' + page).addClass('active');
```

Where `page` is the number passed into the `onclick` method. What complicates this however is that I am using a `PartialView` which is loaded on success of an `ajax` call. So the entire `onclick` method looks like this:

```
function paginationChange(page) {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: '/Projects/ProjectTable/CountProjects',
        data: { searchString: $('#searchBox').val() },
        success: function(result) {
            $('#table-container').load('/Projects/ProjectTable/TestPartialView',
                {
                    searchString: $('#searchBox').val(),
                    currentPage: page,
                    projectCount: result
                }); 
            $('#' + page).addClass('active');
        }
    });
}
```

I have tried moving around the `addClass` call as I thought the issue could be that the `PartialView` is being rendered after I have added the class therefore rendering the element without the class on it.

Is there a way I can wait until the `TestPartialView` has loaded in its entirety and then add the class to the correct `<li>`?

EDIT:

```
<ul id="paginationList" class="pagination">
   <li id="1" class="page-item">
      <a class="page-link" href="#">1</a>
   </li>
</ul>
```

New js:

```
$('#paginationList li.page-item').click(function () {
    console.log('test');
    var $li = $(this);
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: '/Projects/ProjectTable/CountProjects',
        data: { searchString: $('#searchBox').val() },
        success: function(result) {
            $('#table-container').load('/Projects/ProjectTable/TestPartialView',
                {
                    searchString: $('#searchBox').val(),
                    currentPage: page,
                    projectCount: result
                }, function() {
                    $li.addClass('active');
                }); 
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: `Is there a way I can wait until the TestPartialView has loaded in its entirety..` yes, put the `addClass()` call in the callback of the `load()` call.

Comment: Sure, I added an answer for you below with an added improvement to the event binding logic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way I can wait until the TestPartialView has loaded in its entirety and then add the class to the correct `<li>`?

Yes, you can put the `addClass()` call in the callback of the `load()` call.

Also note that using `on*` event handlers are very outdated. As you're using jQuery you can use that to add unobtrusive event handlers to the `li` which then save the need to pass around hard-coded arguments as you will already have a reference to the element which raised the event. Try this:

```
<ul>
  <li class="page-item">
    <a class="page-link" href="#">2</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

```js
$(function() {
  $('li.page-item').click(function() {
    var $li = $(this);

    $.ajax({  
      type: 'GET',
      url: '/Projects/ProjectTable/CountProjects',
      data: { 
        searchString: $('#searchBox').val() 
      },
      success: function(result) {
        $('#table-container').load('/Projects/ProjectTable/TestPartialView', {
          searchString: $('#searchBox').val(),
          currentPage: page,
          projectCount: result
        }, function() {   
          // this argument is a function to be executed once the content has been loaded,
          // similar to the success handler of $.ajax
          $li.addClass('active');
        });             
      }
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Perfect. I've tried to add your improvement by just getting the `'li.page-item'` however now the function isn't occuring at all. Could you check over my edit? I believe it may be because of the `<ul>` having an ID but I've tried to include that in my code.

Comment: Make sure you're running the jQuery logic in a docuement.ready handler. That's what the `$(function() { .. })` wrapper is in my answer. Also check the console for errors. The `id` on the parent `ul` shouldn't have any effect

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way I can wait until the TestPartialView has loaded in its entirety and then add the class to the correct `<li>`

Yes you've just to use the **[`load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load/)** callback that will be called after the partial is fully loaded :

```
$('#table-container').load('/Projects/ProjectTable/TestPartialView',
{
    searchString: $('#searchBox').val(),
    currentPage: page,
    projectCount: result
}, function(){
    $('#' + page).addClass('active');
});
```